# Animation along z axis with additional effect

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I am working on a application where user makes a transaction and the status of transaction is shown on the final page i.e whether it was successful or failed and a image of success stamp or failure stamp is shown which overlays all the views.

I am trying to add a animation like putting a stamp on a paper with hand on success or fail image.

I tried different combinations using ObjectAnimator and Interpolator class but nothing worked.

It will be great if any can help here to find the right approach for doing this.
Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please help to make improvements in the question if its not clear.

Comment: Show some code, what have you tried so far? What's your projects Min API?

Comment: Project's minimum API is 14.. i am able to make animation in x and y axis which looks ok..but in z axis it does not look smooth..

Comment: Show some code of your not smooth animation